# In Dojo Toolkit before 1.14, there is unescaped string injection in dojox/Grid/DataGrid.: CVE-2018-15494

Tags: license, security

We use an older verion of dojo in our product and our upgrade to newer version needs lot of overhauling of the product code - which is not possible at this wee hour. But we need to get rid of this reported vulnerability - CVE-2018-15494. I found that the fix is there in the dojo's two files - https://github.com/dojo/dojox/pull/283

I wanted to know if I can make the changes in my application directly? Are there any license issues?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what licence you got the earlier version of dojo(x?) under, but the [current LICENSE file](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/LICENSE) says either 3BSD or Academic Free License, at your choice.  Were you to choose to take the patch under 3BSD, then assuming that your product is distributed in binary-only form, your major obligation after incorporating this patch would be that

> Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
> this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
> and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

This does not seem to me unduly onerous for a commercial product.  If you can live with that, I think that you may use the patch.  That said, you may wish to take professional legal advice before betting a company on this!